# Objective C chaining properties

Tags: objective-c, llvm-gcc

While this may be a total n00b question, I haven't encountered a situation like this before and was a bit stunned.
I have a few Objective C classes and each has a few properties declared. All properties are properly declared and synthesized.

Simplified, the structure looks something like:

```
CompanyData - hasA - DepartmentInfo - hasA - Office - hasA - Employee - hasA - isFemale(BOOL)
```

If I write something like this:

```
companyData.departmentInfo.office.currentEmployee.isFemale = YES;
```

my code won't compile and I get `"Segmentation fault: 11"` error.

However, if I write:

```
Employee *currentEmployee = companyData.departmentInfo.office.currentEmployee;
currentEmployee.isFemale = YES;
```

everything compiles fine. Why? What am I missing here?

I am using XCode 4.5 and LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.

Comment: If you're getting a SEGFAULT during compilation, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Bug? Or is it really something a compiler can't compile?

Comment: Can you show the definitions of your classes and properties - without those folk can only guess. Also how can you code not compile *and* produce a runtime segmentation fault?

Comment: @Maggie: Feed a compiler Shakespeare, and it still shouldn't SEGFAULT.

Comment: @CRD I will add the exact definition of classes, although I double checked it and evertyhing seems fine.
The error I get is a compile-time error. It just won't compile.

Comment: @Maggie - I've tested this (using basic implementation of your classes) with Xcode 4.6.3, Apple LLVM 4.2 & LLVM GCC 4.2 and it compiles and runs correctly using both compilers. Either there is something else in your code causing the issue or you have a compiler bug. Without more detail I can't say which.

Comment: Thanx, I've tried with XCode 4.3.3 and it works fine as well. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

1. that `isFemale` is properly synthesized. Beware, the `is` keyword is an objective-C <strike>standard</strike> convention (as in `@property (nonatomic, getter=isFemale) BOOL female`). If in doubt, try another property name, such as `femaleGender`.
2. that the `Office` propery `currentEmployee` is of type `Employee` and that the calling class knows about the the `Employee` properties (`#include "Employee.h").

Comment: "the `is` keyword is an objective-C standard" - I don't get it. `is` is not a keyword in Objective-C. It's just fine to call your `BOOL` properties `isXXXX`.

Comment: The `is` prefix for boolean property getters is definitely a common and well known convention. It should be considered "standard" in the only way Objective-C knows: documented and described by Apple documentation.